# Connecting to Metawear via Swift BLE

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I am using a Metawear Motion R board. I want to read the accelerometer and gyroscope data. While the manufacturer does provide a C++ SDK that I can use to read this data, I find it unstable and hard to debug when things go wrong. As a result, I wanted to read the accelerometer and gyroscope data only via Swift.

If I were to use their SDK, code below would let me call and configure the device:

```
// configure accelerometer
mbl_mw_acc_set_odr(self.connectedDevice?.board, 50.0);
mbl_mw_acc_set_range(self.connectedDevice?.board, 4.0);
mbl_mw_acc_write_acceleration_config(self.connectedDevice?.board);

// configure gyroscope
mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_set_odr(self.connectedDevice?.board, MBL_MW_GYRO_BMI160_ODR_50Hz);
mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_set_range(self.connectedDevice?.board, MBL_MW_GYRO_BMI160_RANGE_125dps);
mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_write_config(self.connectedDevice?.board);

// read the accelerometer
let acc_signal = mbl_mw_acc_get_acceleration_data_signal(self.connectedDevice?.board);
mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(acc_signal, bridge(obj: self)) { (context, data) in
    let obj: MblMwCartesianFloat = data!.pointee.valueAs();
    let _self: ExerciseViewController = bridge(ptr: context!);
    _self.add_imu_records(record: ImuRecord(x: obj.x, y: obj.y, z: obj.z, time: Date()), isAccelerometer: true);
}
// read the gyroscope
let gyro_signal = mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_get_rotation_data_signal(self.connectedDevice?.board);
mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(gyro_signal, bridge(obj: self)) { (context, data) in
    let obj: MblMwCartesianFloat = data!.pointee.valueAs();
    let _self: ExerciseViewController = bridge(ptr: context!);
    _self.add_imu_records(record: ImuRecord(x: obj.x, y: obj.y, z: obj.z, time: Date()), isAccelerometer: false);
}

mbl_mw_acc_enable_acceleration_sampling(self.connectedDevice?.board);
mbl_mw_acc_start(self.connectedDevice?.board);
mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_enable_rotation_sampling(self.connectedDevice?.board);
mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_start(self.connectedDevice?.board);
```

To start implementing the configuration and logging logic by only using Swift, I am following two guides: [Decoding metawear](https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/66/decoding-metawear-apis-using-ble-to-read-gyro-sensor) , [Core BLE Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor)

My code base below will connect to the MetaWear device and look at the different characteristics.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

public class BleCommunicator : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    private let metaWearService = CBUUID(string: "326A9000-85CB-9195-D9DD-464CFBBAE75A")
    private let metaWearConfigurationCharacteristic = CBUUID(string: "326A9001-85CB-9195-D9DD-464CFBBAE75A")
    private let metawearDataCharacteristic = CBUUID(string: "326A9006-85CB-9195-D9DD-464CFBBAE75A")
    
    private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    private var myDevice: CBPeripheral!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        case .unknown:
            print("### check ble connection is unknown");
        case .resetting:
            print("### check ble connection is resetting");
        case .unsupported:
            print("### check ble connection is unsupported");
        case .unauthorized:
            print("### check ble connection is unauthorized");
        case .poweredOff:
            print("### check ble connection is poweredOff");
        @unknown default:
            print("### check ble connection");
        }
    }

    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if (peripheral.name == "MetaWear") {
            myDevice = peripheral
            myDevice.delegate = self
            centralManager.stopScan()
            centralManager.connect(myDevice)
        }
    }
    
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        myDevice.discoverServices([metaWearService])
    }
}

extension BleCommunicator : CBPeripheralDelegate {

    public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
    
    public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if (characteristic.uuid == metawearDataCharacteristic) {
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case metawearDataCharacteristic:
            sensor(from: characteristic)
        default:
            print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }
    
    private func sensor(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
        let _ = characteristicData.first else { return }
        let data = String(bytes: characteristicData, encoding: .utf8)
        print("### we have this:: \(data) ");
    }
}
```

Once run, the sensor funciton displays an empty 20 byte array. I suspect this is because the device needs to be configured before data is read. ( As I do in the C++ code block ) The first tutorial mentions sending a pre-formatted pattern to the metawear board via the metaWearConfigurationCharacteristic, as shown below, but I am unable to find any documentation to replicate it:

> Input - 13032600, where 13 is gyro module, 03 is config opcode, 26 is
> output data rate (38 hz), 00 is angular data range.

Question:
How can I configure and read accelerometer and gyroscope sensors, as demonstrated using the C++ code, with Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverse-engineered the C++ SDK, and as a result, I've written this code to initialize the device:

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
    for characteristic in characteristics {
        if (characteristic.uuid == metawearDataCharacteristic) {
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        } else if (characteristic.uuid == metaWearConfigurationCharacteristic) {
            let configurationSeq : [[UInt8]] = createInitSequence()
            for seq in configurationSeq {
                peripheral.writeValue(Data(seq), for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func createInitSequence() -> [[UInt8]]  {
    let sequence : [[UInt8]] = [[3, 4, 1], [19, 5, 1],
                                [3, 2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1],
                                [19, 2, 1,0], [19, 1, 1]]
    return sequence;
}
```

To read the data on notify, I updated the below function to be as follows:

```
private let factorAcceleration: Float = 8192.0000
private let factorGyroscope: Float = 262.399994

private func sensor(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
    let _ = characteristicData.first else { return }
    let data = characteristic.value!
    var values = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data.count)
    data.copyBytes(to: &values, count: data.count)

    if (values[0] == 3) {
        // this is the accelerometer
        let xAxis = Float(Int16(values[2..<4])) / factorAcceleration
        let yAxis = Float(Int16(values[4..<6])) / factorAcceleration
        let zAxis = Float(Int16(values[6..<8])) / factorAcceleration
        print("accelerometer x=\(xAxis), y=\(yAxis), z=\(zAxis)");
    }
    if (values[0] == 19) {
        // this is the gyroscope
        let xAxis = Float(Int16(values[2..<4])) / factorGyroscope
        let yAxis = Float(Int16(values[4..<6])) / factorGyroscope
        let zAxis = Float(Int16(values[6..<8])) / factorGyroscope
        print("gyroscope x=\(xAxis), y=\(yAxis), z=\(zAxis)");
    }
    
}
```

From a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646452/how-to-convert-a-pair-of-bytes-into-a-float-using-swift/62647725#62647725), I parsed the unit8 bytes into a float. This code will allow this conversion:

```
extension Numeric {
    init<D: DataProtocol>(_ data: D) {
        var value: Self = .zero
        let size = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value, { data.copyBytes(to: $0)} )
        assert(size == MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value))
        self = value
    }
}
```