# How to convert a pair of bytes into a Float using Swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using [this article](https://phyphox.org/wiki/index.php/MbientLab_MetaWear_(MetaMotionR)) to communicate with an IoT sensor via BLE. In the article, this quote is mentioned:

> The first two bytes do not seem to belong to the data (probably a prefix to denote that it is a data packet), but the remaining ones are more interesting. For the accelerometer, we get three signed 16 bit integers (little endian), which can simply be scaled to the range we set up to get our setup sequence. So the +/-2^15 range of the signed 16bit integer corresponds to the +/-16g, resulting in a factor 1/2048. To get the acceleration in m/s², we apply a factor of 9.81/2048. So, the corresponding bluetooth part reads:

```
<output char="326a9006-85cb-9195-d9dd-464cfbbae75a" conversion="int16LittleEndian" offset="2" length="2">accXRaw</output>
<output char="326a9006-85cb-9195-d9dd-464cfbbae75a" conversion="int16LittleEndian" offset="4" length="2">accYRaw</output>
<output char="326a9006-85cb-9195-d9dd-464cfbbae75a" conversion="int16LittleEndian" offset="6" length="2">accZRaw</output>
```

To read this code, I am running this Swift code:

```
private func sensor(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
    let _ = characteristicData.first else { return }
    let data = characteristic.value!
    var values = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data.count)
    data.copyBytes(to: &values, count: data.count)
    print("values = \(values)")
}
```

The result once I do a print is:

```
values = [3, 4, 250, 255, 199, 249, 91, 191]
```

Alike the article mentions, I can confirm that the first two bytes do not belong to any data, and are consistently repeating. Bytes values[2-7] are constantly changing, which makes me more confident that the pairs represent accXRaw, accYRaw, and accZRaw. What I want to do now is convert the pairs to doubles.

For example:

```
values[2], values[3] = [250 255] (accXRaw)

values[4], values[5] = [199 249] (accYRaw)

values[6], values[7] = [91 191]  (accZRaw)
```

In the article, the author does this via a int16 little endian. I want to do the same with swift 5, but not sure if I am doing it correctly. Here is my code:

```
let xAxis = Float(bitPattern: UInt32(littleEndian: [values[2], values[3], 0x00, 0x00].withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }))
let yAxis = Float(bitPattern: UInt32(littleEndian: [values[4], values[5], 0x00, 0x00].withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }))
let zAxis = Float(bitPattern: UInt32(littleEndian: [values[6], values[7], 0x00, 0x00].withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }))
    
print("x=\(xAxis), y=\(yAxis), z=\(zAxis)");
```

The resulting printout is:

```
values = [3, 4, 250, 255, 199, 249, 91, 191]

x=9.1827e-41, y=8.9603e-41, z=6.8645e-41
```

These numbers just look weird, and I suspect I am doing something wrong. Am I reading the byte pairs correctly ( at least in line with the article ) ? If not, what mistakes did I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue there is that you are not suppose to initialize your Float using the bitPattern initializer and/or use the UInt32(littleEndian:) initializer. What you need is to convert those 2 bytes to Int16, coerce it to Float and then multiply by the factor of 9.81/2048 to get its acceleration.

Expanding on that, you can create a Numeric initializer that takes an object that conforms to DataProtocol (Data or Bytes [UInt8]):

```
extension Numeric {
    init<D: DataProtocol>(_ data: D) {
        var value: Self = .zero
        let size = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value, { data.copyBytes(to: $0)} )
        assert(size == MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value))
        self = value
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize your Int16 object with the subdata (two bytes).

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [3, 4, 250, 255, 199, 249, 91, 191]
let xData = bytes[2..<4]
let yData = bytes[4..<6]
let zData = bytes[6..<8]

let factor: Float = 9.81/2048

let xAxis = Float(Int16(xData)) * factor
let yAxis = Float(Int16(yData)) * factor
let zAxis = Float(Int16(zData)) * factor

print("x:", xAxis, "y:", yAxis, "z:", zAxis)  // x: -0.028740235 y: -7.6305327 z: -79.27036
```